# Remove groups where there is not at least two difference values within a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as

```
COL1 COL2 SP
G1   A    SP1
G1   A    SP2
G2   B    SP1
G2   B    SP1
G3   C    SP7
G3   C    SP3
G4   A    SP8
G4   A    SP8
```

And I would like to only keep **COL1 COL2** groups where there is at least two different **SP names**.

I would then get:

```
COL1 COL2 SP
G1   A    SP1
G1   A    SP2
G3   C    SP7
G3   C    SP3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `transform` with `nunique`

```
out = df[df.groupby(['COL1','COL2'])['SP'].transform('nunique')>1]
Out[245]: 
  COL1 COL2   SP
0   G1    A  SP1
1   G1    A  SP2
4   G3    C  SP7
5   G3    C  SP3
```

Comment: I changed `==2` to `>1`